Is there any way to connect to Windows Wireless Display through macos?
My school has been using a Windows wireless display to connect to all the projectors in the building. This would normally have been fine as I was mainly a Windows user but have begun moving to MacOS. As far as I can tell there is no native support to send such connections through MacOS.
I have looked through countless videos on YouTube and subreddits and have been unable to find any solution that can do this. The closest thing I found was connecting an airplay receiver to the screen and then connecting to that. If anyone has any solutions or software that I could try that would be very useful.

The underlying technology is called "Miracast", maybe that'll help your research.

Thank you I have been looking at the miracast technology and cannot seem to find any suitable replacement or software that would extend it on a Macbook.
